# QuickBlox : FB user cannot login in the chat

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have created an ios app using QuickBlox ios SDK. In that I have provided manual and Facebook login options. After logged in using Facebook, I could not logged into the chat. But there is no such problem for Manual login. This is the error it is showing:
QBChat/didNotAuthenticate, error:

Is there anything I needed to do specifically after Facebook login inorder to login to the chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please read about chat password http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Password

if you are using social login, password for chat will be equal qb session token

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.ID = 298;
user.password = [BaseService sharedService].token;
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];
```

Comment: you have to use your user id, not from this example

Answer (score 0):

Are you try use this method

```
[QBUsers logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" accessToken:@"my_fb_token" accessTokenSecret:nil delegate:self];
```

with explicit passing of facebook token?